# to_xml Doesn't Work on Objects Returned Through Rails ActiveRecord habtm Reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, reference, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two rails active record classes, School and Instructor linked by a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I need to query my instructors_controller for instructors for a particular school and return an xml format response.  Therefore, in the index method I have this code fragment:

```
school = School.find(params[:school_id])
@instructors = school.instructors
```

and later:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @instructors }
  format.json { render :json => @instructors }
end
```

But it doesn't work.  Look at this intriguing but baffling sequence:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 >   Instructor.all.first
=> #<Instructor id: 1, name: "Mrs. Smith", instructor_type_id: 1, created_at: "2011-07-24 18:19:40", updated_at: "2011-07-24 18:19:40"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 > Instructor.all.first.class
 => Instructor(id: integer, name: string, instructor_type_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > School.first.instructors.first
 => #<Instructor id: 1, name: "Mrs. Smith", instructor_type_id: 1, created_at: "2011-07-24 18:19:40", updated_at: "2011-07-24 18:19:40"> 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > School.first.instructors.first.class
 => Instructor(id: integer, name: string, instructor_type_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :021 > Instructor.all.first.to_xml
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<instructor>\n  <created-at type=\"datetime\">2011-07-24T18:19:40Z</created-at>\n  <id type=\"integer\">1</id>\n  <instructor-type-id type=\"integer\">1</instructor-type-id>\n  <name>Mrs. Smith</name>\n  <updated-at type=\"datetime\">2011-07-24T18:19:40Z</updated-at>\n</instructor>\n"
```

Now for the punchline:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :019 > School.first.instructors.first.to_xml

NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/serializers/xml_serializer.rb:230:in `compute_type'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:22:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:75:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:75:in `block in serializable_attributes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:74:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:74:in `map'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:74:in `serializable_attributes'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:116:in `add_attributes_and_methods'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:103:in `block in serialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:134:in `_nested_structures'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:58:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:31:in `tag!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb:102:in `serialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/serializers/xml_serializer.rb:175:in `to_xml'
    from (irb):19
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@blueprint/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.2-p180 :020 > Instructor.all.first.to_xml
```

What's going on here ?

Edit: Well, switching from xml to json solved the problem, (to_json does not exhibit the same strangeness as to_xml here), although I would still like to know the explanation for the above behavior.

Also, as I am relatively new to Rails, is there a better way to do what I want to do here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to_xml() tries to define a type attribute for each model attribute. For example, a User model with an age (INT) attribute will have: `<age type="integer">42</age>`. This type information is not encoded in JSON, which is why to_json() works for you. Add this method to your Instructor model:

```
def to_xml(options = {})
  to_xml_opts = {:skip_types => true} # no type information, not such a great idea!
  to_xml_opts.merge!(options.slice(:builder, :skip_instruct))
  # a builder instance is provided when to_xml is called on a collection of instructors,
  # in which case you would not want to have <?xml ...?> added to each item
  to_xml_opts[:root] ||= "instructor"
  self.attributes.to_xml(to_xml_opts)
end
```

This would however make your XML devoid of any type information - not good if someone has a JAVA REST client. A better strategy would be to filter `self.attributes.slice(*keys).to_xml(to_xml_opts)` where *keys* is an array of model attributes you want in the XML.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful answer.  I think i could get away with receiving all of my attributes as strings.  Why is the type information lost when accessing instructors through schools accessor?  Is there some way to bring it along ?

Comment: This was a brilliant response Sayantam. Thanks very much.