# rails 3: how can I debug why/where @foo.to_xml throws NoMethodError (undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby, xml, activerecord

@foo is the result of a LEFT JOIN between two activerecord tables, there are nil values as a result of the JOIN when there is no matching row in the second table.

Interestingly, calling @foo.to_yaml is fine.

Calling @foo.to_json is fine.

But calling `@foo.to_xml` throws  the error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'type' for nil:NilClass)`

The same error gets thrown even if I use :skip_types, eg: even if I use `@foo.to_xml(:skip_instruct => true, :skip_types => true)`

How can I make the to_xml work okay on a joined dataset when some of the rows do not have a matching row in the right column?

The JSON and YAML both correctly show the 'missing' fieldnames, but with no value. Only the to_xml is throwing the error.

Comment: Getting same error. Did you see this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808958/to-xml-doesnt-work-on-objects-returned-through-rails-activerecord-habtm-referen

Comment: No I didnt see that, and that looks like the issue, thanks.